# Способы общения между дочерними процессами через дескриптор

Tags: unix, c

Между родительским и дочерним все как то проще (там дочерний наследует открытые файловые дескрипторы), но между дочерними сложнее, дочерний не может открыть дескриптор другого дочернего

Будьте добры, подскажите, но способ должен быть связан с работой через дескриптор
Может можно как то использовать дескрипторы другого процесса?

P.S.: количество дочерних процессов, в течении работы программы, постоянно меняется (пишу сервер, и для каждого подключившегося клиента создаю дочерний процесс).

Comment: А нельзя ли создать доп. пару дескрипторов, запустить дочерние процессы, закрыть в родительском, и пусть через эту пару и общаются?

Comment: забыл сказать: количество дочерних процессов, в течении работы программы, непостоянное количество. Поэтому здесь такое не прокатит

Comment: через pipe  родитель раздаёт детям и настривает а затем закрывает свои , что бы не мешать

Comment: количество дочерних процессов постоянно меняется, тут так не получится: не все дочерние смогут друг с другом связаться

Comment: @knoxx: Тогда вам [сюда](http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node7.html)

Comment: тогда в родителе можно завести монитор и через него менеджит "каналами" т.е у каждого потомка есть пара к монитору на чтение/запись через который идёт запрос на получение  и либо публикация своих контактов 

монитор в свою очередь выполняет роль сводни :)

корочи кури литературу на тему csp

Comment: спасибо, я так понял, что мой выбор - FIFO

Comment: Я, например, люблю работать с socketpair() анонимных неблокирующих unix-сокетов. При любой схеме создания потомков, независимо от их количества и времён появления.

Comment: @knoxx: Пробуйте. Если не подойдёт — там много вариантов, решение найдётся.

Comment: у меня возникла проблемка: если два процесса читают фифошку, третий пишет в фифошку, то первым двум не всегда приходит то, что отсылалось третьим. Это можно побороть?

Comment: @knoxx, что-то не так делаете. Сходу сишные примеры не нахожу, но вот посмотрите: http://www.dcs.ed.ac.uk/home/timh/PERL-CD/cookbook/ch16_11.htm Это perl, но наглядно, все возможные ситуации разобраны по косточкам, и практически 1:1 можно переносить на C. Основная идея в том, что  каналы должны создаваться для каждой пары "родитель-потомок", никакой третий процесс в них вклиниваться не может по определению.

Comment: @klopp, данная проблема на примере отсюда http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node18.html#SECTION00733000000000000000

Comment: Очевидно, вам такой способ просто не подходит.

Comment: P.S. Мне только что приглючился пул сообщений на базе shared memory :) Только нужно хорошо продумать протокол: от кого, кому, как отмечать полученные, и т.д.

И ещё вариант: сам родитель работает как диспетчер сообщений. Ребёнок шлёт сообщение ему, с указанием адресата, а родитель уже разруливает кому его отсылать - конкретному, всем, группе и т.д. Тогда никаких дополнительных каналов создавать и не нужно.

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть как работает Хромиум (http://www.chromium.org/). В архитектуре хрома есть несколько типов процессов, которые общаются между собой по IPC, все команды передаются через "шариную память" (mmf). При большом желании часть кода из хрома можно вытащить отдельными библиотеками, и переиспользовать в своем проекте.

Comment: @knoxx, я толком так и не понял Ваш вопрос.

--

В принципе, в \*nix процессы (даже не обязательно родственные) могут обмениваться открытыми дескрипторами, используя вызов `sendmsg()`. Но, это опять же будет обмен точка-точка.

Например, таким образом сервер может перекинуть пришедший connect ранее запущенному процессу. И тот будет "общаться" с новым клиентом.

В [Unix socket magic](http://www.lst.de/~okir/blackhats/node121.html) есть пример передачи дескриптора процессу.

Но, вот тот ли это способ, что нужен Вам, не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю это Ваш случай, очереди сообщений SVID IPC: msgget, msgctl, msgrcv, msgsnd, ...
[тут небольшой пример кода](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgsnd.2.html)

Comment: Действительно, из-за этого изменения (`MSG_COPY (since Linux 3.8)`, кстати, @dsnk, когда это произошло?) SVID IPC похоже можно применить, хотя это все же не файловый дескриптор о котором просил автор.

Comment: OK / ( Linux 3.8 was released on Mon, 18 Feb 2013) (даа, за полтора года до вопроса...) (и почему комментарий можно править только в течении 5 минут???)

Comment: @avp на сколько понял суть вопроса, требовался способ обмена сообщений между несколькими своими процессами.

Comment: Ну, да. Там в обсуждении в комментариях к вопросу кое-какие детали  проявляются (правда мутновато, додумывать надо). Я и говорю, что теперь (поскольку можно прочесть не удаляя из очереди) вполне можно реализовать на SVID (только блокировки на логику выборки видимо надо делать).